# How to model array of different types in Prisma

Tags: mysql, node.js, prisma

I'm trying to use prisma.io with a mysql database to model a company with different employee types.

I want to put different types of workers (executives, management, worker, temp worker) into an employee array. They will each have their own model and different fields in the database table. In the prisma schema, how do I set this up?

```
model company {
  id                     Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  name                   String   @db.VarChar(255)
  employee         employees[]
}
```

I am trying to achieve something like the above, but each employee could be a different type with its own model. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `employee` field must always refer to the same kind of data model - Prisma fields cannot refer to models of different types.

If two `employee` models could possibly have different fields, you should create smaller models that collect shared fields among those different "sub types", and then assign them as being optionally present on the `employee` model.

```
model CompanyTest {
  id        Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  name      String     @db.VarChar(255)
  employees Employee[]
}

model Employee {
  id                Int                @id @default(autoincrement())
  companyTest       CompanyTest?       @relation(fields: [companyTestId], references: [id])
  companyTestId     Int?
  // executiveEmployee and managerEmployee may or may not exist,
  // but are always accessible from the root Employee model
  executiveEmployee ExecutiveEmployee?
  managerEmployee   ManagerEmployee?
  // maybe add a "type" field here so you know 
  // internally what data is going to be here and can query for it effectively
}

model ExecutiveEmployee {
  id           Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt    DateTime? @default(now())
  lastModified DateTime? @updatedAt
  // executive fields here
  employee     Employee  @relation(fields: [employeeId], references: [id])
  employeeId   Int       @unique
}

model ManagerEmployee {
  id           Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt    DateTime? @default(now())
  lastModified DateTime? @updatedAt
  // manager fields here
  employee     Employee  @relation(fields: [employeeId], references: [id])
  employeeId   Int       @unique
}
```